# how to swap php variable characters around

Tags: php, ios, int

I am trying to use a formula which requires me to mix the characters of a variable around. I am fairly new to PHP and am slightly confused with the lack of format specifications like in other languages.

the php script is being passed/(POST) two objective-c integers from my app, here is my php code I have so far, its pretty simple its more of a proof of concept and figuring out if the variable coming into my script is still int or a string or whatever the heck it might be.. slightly confused with php and the lack of having to declare format specifications etc.

```
<?php

$inputDate = $_REQUEST['userDate']; //example of whats coming in 12345678

//swap the 4 characters around
//23416587 (this is not random)


//then send result back

?>
```

So, the first question would be, when $inputDate is instantiated with '12345678' is it an integer? or can I still perform string manipulation to mix the numbers like I have shown above?

Comment: What is it that you want to do exactly? If you want to reverse string use strrev();

Comment: `<?php echo implode(shuffle(explode("",$_REQUEST['userDate']))); ?>`

Comment: well I want to know first of all, when I pass the objective-c integer into $inptDate what is the format of inputDate? from there I need to figure out how to mix the characters of variable around.... also there is a specific order in which I have to mix the characters in order for the app to produce the correct outcome.

Comment: Show us some example input and result please.

Comment: I have updated the main question with more information for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original value of  `$_REQUEST['userDate'];` is probably a string. To be safe, cast it with `(string)$_REQUEST['userDate']` or append an empty string.  To get the order you desire, you could do:

```
$inputDate = (string)$_REQUEST['userDate'];

//12345678 to 23416587

$formatted_date = $inputDate[1].$inputDate[2].$inputDate[3].
                  $inputDate[0].$inputDate[5].$inputDate[4].
                  $inputDate[7].$inputDate[6];

//use (int) or intval() if you need it to be an integer first
//then send back to your app
```

Since you are fairly new to PHP, let me just say that [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and error reporting are your friends:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: okay cool.. this is what I was hoping I could do I just had no idea if it was an int or a string or array etc.. :) I will try that now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @C.Johns PHP in some regards is a "loosely typed" or "weak typed" language meaning variables can take on different representations. Google it a bit to get more information as that may help you on your project. Good luck :D

Comment: @C.Johns see updated answer. Try explicity casting to a string. Also, make sure that there are only linebreaks between `$inputDate[3].$inputDate[0]` and `$inputDate[4].              $inputDate[7]` and not any spaces

Comment: DONT LISTEN TO ME!!! lol I somehow removed one of the concatenation '.' dots and couldnt see it because of the red error line underneath the code :P:P sorry man, works perfectly :)

Comment: @TheCapn, thanks for that I think I remember something being said at uni about this.. but having taken so many papers everything tends to blur into one big mess after a while. Will have to digg out my old notes again I think :)

Comment: So, after doing the var_dump and realizing I was getting some bung results I realized that this is not quite what I was after, however it is a step in the right direction, I thought $inputDate[1] was the first index of inputdate.. but it seems that its actually putting that value into $inputDate.. so need to figure that out.